# Protect SQLite Statements (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android application which using SQLite contacts DB.
The user inserts new contact details, pushes a button and new contact should be inserted to DB.
Anyway, user can insert illegal characters or words, such as "'" or "DELETE" which can cause problems.
How can I avoid it? Should I use patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Use a compiled [`SQLiteStatement`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html)